# How to open a WPF Content Stream?

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, uri

Here's the code snippet

```
String str= ??????? // I want to assign c:/my/test.html to this string
Uri uri= new Uri (str);
Stream src = Application.GetContentStream(uri).Stream;
```

What's the correct way to do this? I'm getting "URI not relative" Exception thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is specific to WPF. See the [`Application.GetContentStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.getcontentstream.aspx) method.

You'll read that this method requires a relative URI. See "[WPF Application, Resource, Content and Data files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx)".

Answer (score 1):

You have a file path - if you want to make it a URI add "file:///", ie. "file:///c:/my/test.html"

Comment: Thanks. But, I get a "URI not relative" exception with that

Answer (score 0):

For local file URIs, you need to prefix it with:

```
file:///
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your problem is that [Application.GetContentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.application.getcontentstream.aspx) is for a resource stream for a **content** data file that is located at the specified Uri. That is, deployed alongside an executable assembly.

If you look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494(VS.90).aspx#Site_of_Origin_Files

You should find that the file:/// syntax as stated above is correct... But if you're going to open them you'll probably want some kind of switch to work out how to get the stream:

```
FileInfo fileToSave;
if (!existingFile.IsFile)
    throw new ArgumentException("Input URI must represent a local file path", "existingFile");

fileToSave = new FileInfo(existingFile.LocalPath);
return fileToSave.Open(/* Args based on your needs */)
```

And similarly if it's a web URI:

```
if (!existingFile.Scheme.StartsWith("http"))
    throw new ArgumentException("Input URI must represent a remote URL path", "existingFile");
// Do a WebRequest.Create call and attempt download... (Perhaps to MemoryStream for future use)
```

Hope that helps.

Andrew.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm having a COM nightmare(too much plumbing to do a simple task). Let me back that up even more of what exactly I'm looking for. I'm writing a tool that converts a .chm file to a .pdf file that fits into an Amazon kindle DX.

For that I need a simple Browser control which loads the .html files  (unzipped by the chmdecompiler) to see if it fits 6 X 8 size (most .html dynamically fits the size except the ones with <pre> tag or with a large image).